# Variable does not exist: ContentNote

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, contentversion, 2gp, contentnote

We are trying to create the version of the 2GP managed package in a Scratch Org in Salesforce. But Getting alot of Errors related to 'ContentNote'.kindly Suggest us the solution for this error.
[image]

Comment: Can you check "Notes" enabled in your scratch org or not?

Comment: Yes i have enabled the notes in the Org, but still the error is same

Answer (score 0):

Your build org is configured incorrectly. When you [create a package version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_create_pkg_ver.htm), you specify a `--definitionfile` argument, which takes a [scratch org definition file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm).

The build org, in which the package version is created, is set up using the features and [settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_settings.htm) from your definition file.

For `ContentNote` to be available in the build org, you must specify the required settings in your definition file:

```
    "enhancedNotesSettings": {
      "enableEnhancedNotes": true
    }
```

The Metadata API settings entity is [`EnhancedNotesSettings`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_enhancednotessettings.htm).